# How to connect to ZTE-MDU devices over python telnet

Tags: python, automation, telnet

it's the code I'm using

```
import getpass
import sys
import telnetlib
import time

Host="something"

user=input("Enter User name")
password=getpass.getpass()

tn = telnetlib.Telnet(Host)
tn.read_until(b"Username: ")
tn.write(user.encode('ascii') + b"\n")
print("Username inserted\n")

if password:
    tn.read_until(b"Password: ")
    tn.write(password.encode('ascii')+b"\n")
    print("Password inserted\n")
    time.sleep(2)
    tn.write(b"enable\n")
    print("enabled\n")
    time.sleep(2)
    tn.write(b"somepassword\n")
    print("enabled success\n")
    time.sleep(2)
    tn.write(b"show running-config\n")
    print("command inserted\n")
    time.sleep(2)
    tn.write("exit\n")
    line=tn.read_all()
    print(line)
```

The MDU is working correctly and connected over telnet but not with the code, it's not displaying any error just nothing. The code is running but displaying nothing.

I wanted to collect all the config in the switch, OLT and routers by connected remotely by using telnet.